# Open folder Path on click of folder icon

Tags: html, jquery

In the folder Icon I have value specified as path on click of folder icon I want to open the particular path in my local desktop

How can I do this?

```html
<i class="ion-folder" data-toggle="tooltip" value="c://Projects" data-html="true" data-container="body" data-placement="top" title="Open Folder"></i>
```

Comment: Can you adapt something like this which uses an image for your purposes?  https://www.aspsnippets.com/demos/2140/

Comment: See here for more info: https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Open-Fileupload-Upload-File-on-Image-Click-using-JavaScript-and-jQuery.aspx

Comment: @finiteloop I have a path specified in value field .I just want to navigate to that path on click

Comment: help me  needed in programming to open folder in local-desktop

Answer (score 1):

You can embedd your Image in a link like:

`<a href="file://LocalDisc:/FOLDER_PATH" target="explorer.exe"><img src="IMAGE_PATH"></a>`

Then you can click on the image and the linked path opens in the browser.

To open the folder on your desktop you need to do some programming.

Comment: Can I get help in programming to open the folder

Comment: @kavya I am sorry, this is beyond my skills. Maybe another user or online research will help you.

Comment: @kavya you also should edit your question and specify your requirement, about wanting to pop up an explorer folder. At the moment it can be read quite misleading.